# SVNKit Alternative Documentation

Tags: java, javadoc, svnkit

I have scoured google for a while, but I have been unable to find a source for the javadoc for SVNKit (all I found was someone's year old github mirror of the SVNKit repository).  Since the SVNKit website is down, does anyone know where I can either access a copy of the web based javadoc or download the javadoc jars for the latest (stable) version of SVNKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking advantage of public maven repos (either manual or from your IDE if your project is maven-based):

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.7.8/svnkit-1.7.8-sources.jar
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.7.8/svnkit-1.7.8-javadoc.jar

Answer (score 0):

SVNKit site is up and running now, sorry for the inconvenience.